# What role is needed to see programmability node in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find out what role is required to see the `Programmability` node in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

The DBO role can see it, but we are trying to give our developers access to see the stored procedures, functions, database triggers and types they are writing without giving them full admin access on our Prod systems.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they will need VIEW DEFINITION on the object (or schema the object resides in perhaps) you can give the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission as a server level permission to avoid having to specify this on all DBs individually.

[View Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175808%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[View Any Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189077%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)